# Need help with an IR spectrum (polymer identification)

Tags: polymers, identification, ir-spectroscopy

I have been given an unknow polymer and I have to identify it.

DSC measurements showed **no glass transition** (which means it's below room temperature) and a **melting temperature at around 100-120°C.** So, I thougth it was a polyethylene. But then, the IR spectrum showed some bands that I didn't expect.

[image]

The only thing I'm sure about are the peaks at around 2900 being C-H streching.

Maybe the large band between 3200-3400 is an O-H bonded? At 3500 cm-1 a N-H ? 1370 I really don't know...

I don't find any corresponding polymer. Could it be a copolymer ? Or an impurity ?

Could you help me please ?